# Спец символы и расположение папок / Gulp

Tags: gulp, символы

Как в gulp указать, чтобы скопировать папку вместе с содержимым, что-то типо? gulp.src('src/icons/*)
Например, необходимо перекинуть папку icons вместе **со всем содержимым** в папку build.
Где можно посмотреть значение этих символов вроде /* , *.*, ** и т.д.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Как скопировать каталог вместе с содержимым:
  Создать таск на вашем примере с gulp.src('src/icons/):

```js
gulp.task('copy', function() {
  gulp.src('src/icon/**/*')//копирует все содержимое вместе с вложеными каталогами
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
});
```

** -использованные в маске пути выбирает подкаталоги.
* -любые символы, в нашем случае, любые символы в имени файла.
Маска 'src/icon/**/*' выберет все содержимое src/icon/.

- Посмотреть значение этих символов вроде / , ., ** и т.д. можно в [документации(eng)](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer)